# Persisting empty sets in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to persist an empty HashSet in App Engine.  It persists fine but when I pull the the item that contains the HashSet from the data-store the HashSet is now null.  What can I do to force App Engine to store an empty HashSet?  Or, do I just need to check for null and create the HashSet each time until it has something in it? I'm guessing I would create a field hashSetEmpty and not create the HashSet till I ran code that added to the HashSet.

Comment: Are you using JDO, JPA, or the low level api?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the HashSet field with a new, empty HashSet before persisting, ideally during class/field initialization.

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "false")
public class POJO implements IsSerializable, Serializable {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @Persistent
    public HashSet<String> hashSet = new HashSet<String>();
}
```

Comment: I do this in the constructor.  the next time I read hashSet it gives me a null pointer exception